# Error: "Cannot resolve method 'makeHttpRequest' in 'JSONParser'"

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to use the 'JSONParser' method 'makeHttpRequest' in my Android app to get some json obejcts from a php script which get some data from a mySql db.
Trying to build the project I'm getting the error "Cannot resolve method 'makeHttpRequest' in 'JSONParser'".

I don't know how to fix it, I searched online for some solutions but found nothing that could fix it.

````
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_user_detail = "https://localhost/android_connect/get_user_details.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        onStart();
    }

    public void log(View view){
        EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        String account_username=username.getText().toString();
        String account_password=password.getText().toString();
        new getUserRole().execute(account_username, account_password);
        //todo
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete userj details
     * */
    class getUserRole extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting user details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(final String... params) {
            int success;
            String result=null;
            try {

                // getting user details by making HTTP request
                // Note that user details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_user_detail, "GET", params); //       <----------
                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single User Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received user details
                    JSONArray roleObj = json
                            .getJSONArray("role"); // JSON Array

                    // get first user object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject role = roleObj.getJSONObject(0);
                    result= role.toString();

                }else{
                    // user not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

How do you import json-simple - is it the same one as this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can see in [the source](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java) that this method does not exist. If you're following some tutorial, make sure to include the correct dependencies